# Highstock Data Grouping to Use Last Data Time as Index

Tags: highcharts

In Highstock (1.3.1) dataGrouping a group is indexed by using the date/time of the first data in the group.

Given we have the following 1 minute OHLC data time:

> **[08:59, 09:00, 09:01, 09:02, 09:03, 09:04, 09:05, 09:06, 09:07, 09:08]**

Currently, if we group this into 5 minute...

- 1st group will be **[08:59]** with **08:55** as index
- 2nd group will be **[09:00, 09:01, 09:02, 09:03, 09:04]** with **09:00** as index
- 3rd group will be **[09:05, 09:06, 09:07, 09:08]** with **09:05** as index

What I want is...

- 1st group should be **[08:59, 09:00]** with **09:00** as index
- 2nd group should be **[09:01, 09:02, 09:03, 09:04, 09:05]** with **09:05** as index
- 3rd group should be **[09:06, 09:07, 09:08]** with **09:10** as index

I think what I want is the same with how they implemented grouping in Google Finance.

There is currently no available option in Highstock to do this.
Maybe the only way to implement this is to modify a few line of codes in Highstock library.
But how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to change this by modifying `seriesProto.groupData` function. There is grouping and approximation applied.

Also you can change smoothed option, so set it to true, and:

```
    if (dataGroupingOptions.smoothed) {
        i = groupedXData.length - 1;
        groupedXData[i] = xMax;
        while (i-- && i > 0) {
            groupedXData[i] += interval / 2; // remove '/2' -> it will create delay to group to last point
        }
        groupedXData[0] = xMin;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you Pawel. Enabling the dataGrouping smoothed will use the last item's date as index. But the grouping itself must also be changed as per my example. I'm sorry but I am new to HighStock. Will you be able to show me how to update the grouping in seriesProto.groupData? Thanks

Comment: Could you create jsFiddle with that data and that problem? I will look into this.