# How on Highstock (highcharts) data grouping shift grouping to the right

Tags: javascript, highcharts

have a question regarding highstock option data grouping. If i use this on big data like 5 years of data for each day. data grouping losses last point if range is set to max. how to prevent this by shifting data grouping timestamps to the right. that it always will end up with last data point.

Comment: Could you please add some code of your chart? That would be helpful to better answer your question. Thank you!

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/2/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/stock/xaxis/labels-formatter/ 
same as basic example if you change to maximum the last point with date 21st disappears

Comment: Check the answer from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18754526/highstock-data-grouping-to-use-last-data-time-as-index It worked for me.